# Get appxmanifest splash screen image and background programatically

Tags: uwp

I'm building an UWP library to implement some common app features such as an extended splash screen, which obviously must look like the app's.

Is there any way to get the splash screen's image and background color programmatically, in an app I don't control?

(of course I can let the app developer specify them somewhere, but it'd be nice to avoid duplication and make it "just work" :) )

Comment: With user, do you mean end-user or developer?

Comment: Developer, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Approach #1

After all, the appxmanifest is just an XML file (right click it in Solution Explorer and choose *View Code* to examine it), and it will be deployed as part of your app package. This means you're able to read its contents from within the app:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("AppxManifest.xml", LoadOptions.None);
var xnamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10");

var visualElementsNode = doc.Descendants(xnamespace + "VisualElements").First();
var backgroundColor = visualElementsNode.Attribute("BackgroundColor").Value;

var splashScreenNode = visualElementsNode.Descendants(xnamespace + "SplashScreen").First();
var splashScreenPath = splashScreenNode.Attribute("Image").Value;
```

Note that the value of the `BackgroundColor` attribute may contain either a hex color code (`#RRGGBB`) or a known color specifier (e.g., `Red`, `CornflowerBlue`, `Transparent`, etc.), so you'll need to put a little extra effort in decoding this value for reuse.

In addition, you should of course be careful to do null checks, catch exceptions, etc. as this code snippet is based on assumptions that may not hold in future versions of the framework (e.g. MS might change the XML schema etc.)

### Approach #2

Since your aim is just to *avoid duplication*, an alternative solution could be to ask developers to specify App color and splash screen image somewhere else, and afterwards fill the appxmanifest with those values. How to accomplish this depends on the exact use case you're building:

- If you're able to intercept the build / app packaging process, you might manipulate the appxmanifest file just before it gets added to the app package.
- If you're creating a [Visual Studio project template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx), you could declare those two values as [custom template parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247063(v=vs.100).aspx) so that any developer using the template is asked to specify both App color and splash screen image when creating the project. Use the `$customParameter$` syntax to reference those value both within C# code and in the appxmanifest file, e.g.: `<uap:SplashScreen Image="$appSplashScreenImage$" />`. Note, however, that the developer obviously may alter these values afterwards. In addition, when following this approach you'll need to make sure that template parameters are replaced within the appxmanifest file, as I described in [the following blog post](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1491&lang=en).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up reading the manifest, with some reflection to translate the colors. https://gist.github.com/SolalPirelli/2fc17e65abdddfcf695dae7f45255477 for anyone else interested.

Comment: Small correction in case somebody's reading this later; the `BackgroundColor` to use is the one in the `SplashScreen` element, not in the parent `VisualElements` element.